# A sequence of random variables with bounded variance

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> If $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of random variable with bounded variance:
>   $$E|X_n^2|\le M<\infty,$$ and $X_n\to X$ in $L^1$, show that
>   $$E|X^2|\le M.$$

I tried to use Fatou's lemma, Cauchy-Schwarz ... , but I failed to prove it. Can anyone give some hint?

Comment: Is it $E(|X|^2)$ or $E(|X|)^2$ ?

Comment: The first one. I've edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following fact is well known (and strongly related to the [Riesz-Fisher theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Fischer_theorem#Completeness_of_Lp.2C_.C2.A00.C2.A0.3C_p.C2.A0.E2.89.A4_.E2.88.9E)):

> If $X_n$ tends to $X$ in $L^1$, we can find a subsequence $X_{\phi(n)}$ such that $X_{\phi(n)}$ tends to $X$ both in $L^1$ and almost surely.

Applying Fatou's lemma to this subsequence yields
$$
E(|X|^2) = E(\liminf_{n\to\infty} |X_{\phi(n)}|^2) \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} E(|X_{\phi(n)}|^2) \leq M.
$$
Therefore $E(|X|^2) \leq M$, and $E(|X|)^2 \leq M$ also holds because of Jensen's inequality (or Cauchy-Schwarz's if you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

$$E|X|=E(|X-X_n+X_n|)\le E(|X-X_n|)+E|X_n|\ \forall n$$ Since $X_n\stackrel{1}{\to} X$, $\forall \epsilon>0$, for large enough $n$, $E|X-X_n|\le \epsilon$ Hence $$E|X|\le \epsilon +\sqrt{M}$$ for all $\epsilon>0\implies E|X|\le \sqrt{M} $.

---

In general, if $E|X_n^p|\le M$ and $X_n\stackrel{p}{\to}X$, $p\ge 1$, then $E|X^p|\le M$. This can be proved in a manner identical to the above, only using [Minkowski's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: Your answer is nice. I'm sorry for my typo and Siméon's answer is what I need.

Comment: I perfectly agree with you @EclipseSun. Simeon's answer is much better than mine and I also upvoted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

$var \{X\}=E\{(X-E\{X\})^2\}$=$E\{X^2\}-(E\{X\})^2$.
  Taking the Schwarz's inequality $E^2\{|xy|\}<E\{|x|^2\}E\{|y|^2\}$ and setting 
y $\equiv 1$  we get $E^2\{|x|\}<E\{|x|^2\}$ so if $E\{|x|^2\}$ is bounded than $E^2\{|x|\}$ must be bounded

Comment: The OP is talking about a sequence of random variables. You are talking about a single random variable. There is a difference.